# What's the deal with this "untagged" tag?

Tags: support, tags

As far as I can tell, the [untagged](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) doesn't seem to be an actual tag (it looks like it's the same thing as the categorized category in wordpress). What's up with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a "tag" that's added when the question is only tagged with low-occurrence tags that don't see enough use and are removed by an automatic monthly process.

See a more detailed description [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags/48418#48418).

Comment: I'll get on and tag them now.